# SCDF server pod is not coming up with containerd

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Our k8s environment is recently upgraded to use contianerd as the default platform and with that change, SCDF servers pods fail with the error below :

Error: failed to create containerd container: create container failed validation: containers.Labels: label key and value greater than maximum size (4096 bytes), key: io.buildpa: invalid argument

Do we have any solution or workaround at this time ? The same image worked perfectly fine with the Docker being the default container engine before.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of containerd are you using?
I think the issue has been fixed in containerd 1.4.2

With older version, you might do the following workaround in `/etc/containerd/config.toml`

```
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd]'
    disable_snapshot_annotations = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a container as a service environment hosted by our company and we don't have access to change containerd configs. Is it possible to rebuild sfdc images by removing the problem causing labels ?

Comment: It's technically possible. I think images built by cloud native buildpack have such labels. You can build images with jib instead (as previous releases), it shouldn't have the issue above.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact error in containerd 1.4.12, however containerd 1.4.11 seems to be fine